# When Using UITabBarController, all view controllers receive shouldAutoRotate or just the displayed one?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, notifications, autorotate

If I have a UITabBarController, displayed 4 view controllers: vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4.
when vc1 is displayed, I rotate the device.
Will all the view controllers receive and run the AutoRotate methods (shouldAutoRotate, willAutoRotate) or just vc1?

If only vc1: should I just send a notification and register all the vc's for it in order so they'll rotate as well? Because I don't want to rotate vc1 to landscape, then go to vc2 and it'll still be on landscape.

Btw - if it matters - I use a different xib for portrait&landscape.

Tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of how your app is constructed. You should have some kind of ViewController that would hold your other viewControllers. So you could do something like this:

```
-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    NSLog(@"Main will rotate");

    [view1 willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    [view2 willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    [view3 willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    [view4 willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}
```

In this case, all your UIViewControllers would rotate because the one who hold them is rotating and making his children rotate. :)

I really like this approach because you don't need to have references to the others viewControllers from each viewController. (view1 doesn't need to know that there is view2,view3 and a view4).

Comment: How exactly does that VC manage the other VC's? because the VC that should hold the other VC's is actually the tab bar...

I'm also having difficulties implementing this because It's quite complicated to alter my application as its been a long time since I've built the basic VC's structure and its quite complicated now.

I have thought of something like accessing self.tabBarController.viewControllers, but for some reason it doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: EDIT: I have just made that way work. I dont know why but it won't send willRotateToInterfaceOrientation, but If I call a method I made myself to rotate, it will work. just loop through self.tabBarController.viewControllers and send the message to all objects that != self. it's quite nice.